# Unix shell script Date format

Tags: shell, unix

I'm looking for a Date for like `Mar  1` (i.e. space+padded space of day of month)

This is giving correct format => `Mar  1`

```
date -d "yesterday 13:00" +"%b %e"
```

However, when I try to put into a variable, the extra added space is missing.

```
DATE=`date -d "yesterday 13:00" +"%b %e"`
echo $DATE gives=> Mar 1 (only padded space getting)
```

Any idea how to get that => `Mar  1` (i.e. space+padded space of day of month)

Answer (score 0):

For lots of details, see [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) or [I just assigned a variable, but echo $variable shows something else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Basically, you need to quote your variable when you use it:

```
echo "$DATE"
```